# What is the best practice to let users set a variable which is then be available for all views?

Tags: django, django-views, global-variables

The app I'm working on is a kind of an internal portal for the big Holding (Group of Companies), where various financial and non-financial data stored for all the companies of the Holding. Users are logging into the portal and on the home page they see the list of all Companies that they are authorized to see.

Then user should be able to enter into one particular Company from the list and afterwards all subsequent views should show data filtered only for that selected Company until user does not exit it and enter into another Company from home page.

I'm trying to achieve this functionality by following but I'm not sure is it proper django way to do it:

1. In views.py I have Mylogin view which is setting global variable Selected_Company='None' when User logs in.
2. Then when User selects any particular Company to work with that Selected_Company variable gets that company's name as a value.
3. All other views which show company related data have a django filter showing model objects matching with the value of Selected_Company.

If you know any other proper way to do it, I'd appreciate your advice.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
One way is to have the URLs structure in a way that the company PK is present in the URL. For example:

```
/accounts/login/               # login; no company selected
/company/                      # list of companies; no company selected
/company/14/                   # company 14 was selected
/company/14/invoices/          # list of invoices of company 14
/company/14/invoices/create/   # add an invoice for company 14
/company/14/purchases/
/company/14/sales/
```

The urlconf would look like this:

```
...
url(
    r'^company/',
    include([
        url(r'^$', views.CompanyListView.as_view()),
        url(
            r'^(?P<company_id>[0-9]+)/',
            include([
                url(r'^$', views.CompanyReadView.as_view()),
                url(r'^invoices/$', views.InvoiceListView.as_view()),
                url(r'^invoices/create/$', views.InvoiceCreateView.as_view()),
...
```

I hope that explains the point I am trying to make. The filtering in the views would be done using the company PK that is obtained from the URL. In the view code, that could look like this:

```
class InvoiceListView(ListView):
    model = Invoice

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            company_id=self.request.kwargs['company_id'])
```

---

**Option 2:**
Another way I could think of is setting the selected company in the session and using the session info to filter in the views. Maybe like this:

```
class InvoiceListView(ListView):
    model = Invoice

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            company_id=self.request.session['company_id'])
```